# How can I move chart control code from Winform to a dll, while keeping chart object in Winform?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, class

I developed a Winform app containing among others many charts. I need to share my VB project with customer, so that he is able to do small changes, but I would like to keep my chart code secret. My idea is to keep all chart objects in Winform, but the code responsible for manipulating the charts and filling them with data to be in a referenced dll file. I am not sure whether this is possible at all. What I did so far is below.

1. I separated chart code in a class (Class1) in the same project with the Winform (Form1). When you press a button on the form a MySQL query is executed in Winform class and Datatable (Tab) is filled and then passed to a procedure in the class (DisplayCharts), where is chart code. All works fine and charts are populated with data. See below some declaration code. Chart object "Modifiers" field is set to Public.

Winform class header and Datatable declaration:

```
Public Class Form1
    Public Shared Tab As New DataTable
```

Class 1 header, procedure and part of chart code:

```
Public Class Class1

    Public Shared Sub DisplayCharts(tab As DataTable)

        Form1.Chart1.DataSource = tab

        Form1.Chart1.Legends.Add("Legends 1")
        Form1.Chart1.ChartAreas.Add("ChartArea1")
        Form1.Chart1.Series.Add("Series 1")
```

Calling the procedure in Winform class:

```
Class1.DisplayCharts(Tab)
```

2. As I read in forums to get the DLL I need to create a new VB project from type "Class Library" and then to copy there Form1 and Class1 after deleting the default new class created by VS. Before copying I added the missing references and namespaces needed for Winform. But I can't get rid of error "Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference" when refering Chart1 in Winform from Class1:
   [image]
3. What else I did is to create a new "Windows Forms Control Library", copy there Form1 and Class1. I had no issues with references and namespaces or any other errors. Project was compiled, dll generated successfully. I moved the dll (WindowsControlLibrary1.dll) to a Winform project containing only Form1 and referenced that dll. I am calling the procedure like following:

```
WindowsControlLibrary1.Class1.DisplayCharts(Tab)
```

But nothing happens and chart remains empty. When I put just as a test a MsgBox in the class, then message is displayed, so procedure is called but there is no interaction from the class in dll with Winform chart.

Apparently I am doing something wrong and any help will be appreciated, provided that my problem has a solution at all. Thank you!

Comment: Pass the Chart reference to the Library.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Aren't you passing `tab As DataTable`? Then you can pass `theChart As Chart` What are those squiggles trying to notify you?

Comment: If I declare in Form1 `Public Shared Chart1 As New System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart` then the error is **'Chart1' is already declared as 'Public WithEvents Chart1 As System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart' in this class.**

Comment: You have to pass the **existing** Chart object, which is `Chart1`. That's the reference you use to draw your charts. You cannot build a new one.

Comment: Oh, yes, you were completely right. Thank you! What I did is following. Point1 from above - the procedure in Class1 was declared with chart argument as `Public Shared Sub DisplayCharts(tab As DataTable, chart1 As Chart)`. Before that you need to add in project following namespace _System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart_ After that this proc is called with `Class1.DisplayCharts(Tab, Chart1)`. Then you save project and move to point 2 for DLL creation. After that copy project in point 1 to new place, delete existing Class1, reference the DLL and voila :)